# Getting the issuer or subject hash from a server's SSL certificate

Tags: curl, wget, openssl, certificates, https

Is there a way to check the issuer of subject hash of some server's SSL certificate?

I know that `curl` or `wget` search for the matching root certificate in `/var/lib/ca-certificates/openssl` or `/etc/ssl/certs` (or some other distribution specific location) according to a specific hash.

The reason I'm asking is that sometimes a certificate gets expired, and I need to know which of my certificate files got expired so I could download a new one. But I can't seem to find a way (except for using `strace`) to see which on of the certificates I need to update.

When I run a command (either `curl` or `get`) through `strace`, I can see which root certificate it opens:

```
$ strace -e trace=open /usr/bin/curl https://git.kernel.org
...
open("/var/lib/ca-certificates/openssl/4042bcee.0", O_RDONLY) = 7
...
```

And I can get the information about the root certificate:

```
$ readlink -f /var/lib/ca-certificates/openssl/4042bcee.0
/var/lib/ca-certificates/openssl/ISRG_Root_X1.pem

$ openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -hash -in /var/lib/ca-certificates/openssl/ISRG_Root_X1.pem
issuer= /C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
subject= /C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
4042bcee
```

I see the certificate from the server was issued by **"Let's Encrypt"**, but it doesn't seem to contain any information that could help me find my relevant root certificate.

```
curl -sv https://git.kernel.org 2>&1 > /dev/null  |sed -n '/SSL/,/SSL/p'
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=ams.source.kernel.org
*  start date: Jan 15 18:02:38 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 15 18:02:37 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "git.kernel.org" matched cert's "git.kernel.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

I've also tried to check the subject hash through the following command (my environment is behind a proxy), and it doesn't match what I see.

```
$ openssl s_client -proxy myproxy:myport -connect git.kernel.org:443 -servername git.kernel.org < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -hash
issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
subject=CN = ams.source.kernel.org
1c27cb82
```

The hash of the server's certificate (**1c27cb82**) doesn't match the hash of my own certificate (**4042bcee**).

So how do `curl` and `wget` know the hash of the root certificate it should look for? And how can I do the same using a command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I only checked the certificate of the site, but I haven't checked the entire certificate chain, most importantly the root CA certificate.

To solve this, I first I had to use the `-showcerts` flag to the `openssl s_client` command to show the entire certificate chain.

Then I ran `openssl` in a loop to check all the certificate provided. I also  checked the `-issuer_hash` in addition to `-hash` (which is a synonym for `-subject_hash`).

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -proxy myproxy:myport -connect git.kernel.org:443 -servername git.kernel.org < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | (while openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -subject_hash -issuer_hash 2>/dev/null; do true; done)
issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
subject=CN = ams.source.kernel.org
1c27cb82
8d33f237
issuer=C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
subject=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
8d33f237
4042bcee
issuer=O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
subject=C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
4042bcee
2e5ac55d
```

Then I could see the expected hash (`4042bcee`) as the subject hash of the third certificate, and the issuer hash of the second certificate in the chain.